# Determine size of used memory in IWICStream buffer

Tags: c++, windows, memory, com, stream

I have VirtualAlloc()'d a 10MB block of memory and initialized an [IWICStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with it using [`IWICStream::InitializeFromMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I encoded a PNG into the IWICStream but I don't know how much memory the PNG data has occupied.

How do I determine the valid/used size of the IWICStream buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IWICStream inherits IStream.  The standard trick is to use [IStream::Seek()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifying STREAM_SEEK_CUR after you've written the image.  The *plibNewPosition argument gives you the length.